# CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have one testing project created following one tutorial and was working correctly. Now I reinstalled my os and installed the latest version of android studio.
And now I got the following error when creating the google map:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
```

my manifest:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="........."/>
```

and here my fragment:

```
public class ZooMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    public static ZooMapFragment getInstance() {
        ZooMapFragment fragment = new ZooMapFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(39.7500, -104.9500))
                .zoom(16f)
                .bearing(0.0f)
                .tilt(0.0f)
                .build();

        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position), null);
        getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        getMap().setTrafficEnabled(true);
        getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(39.7500, -104.9500));
        options.title("ZoO");
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
        getMap().addMarker(options);

        getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return  true;
            }
        });

        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(getString(R.string.pins_feed))
                .build();

        PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(PinsApiInterface.class);
        pinsApiInterface.getStreams(new Callback<List<Pin>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Pin> pins, Response response) {
                if (pins == null || pins.isEmpty() || !isAdded())
                    return;

                for (Pin pin : pins) {
                    Log.e("Zoo", pin.getName());
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(pin.getLatitude(), pin.getLongitude()));
                    options.title(pin.getName());
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    getMap().addMarker(options);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("Log", "Retrofit error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my question is:

Why is my application failing? And what could be different on this version?

Comment: I don't think you did but just to be safe, you didn't run it in the emulator right, cause there it doesn't work

Comment: I'm running this in genymotion, before as well

Comment: If you have an available device I strongly suggest you to use that one because it might not work with emulators!

Comment: yes it works, I just took a old android and it works the map. any idea why its not working on AVD or genymotion?

Comment: I added an answer, if you want to accept since that solve your problem I'll be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I'll go ahead and post it as an answer in case some stuck with the same problem.

Because you are dealing with maps the emulators might point out errors even in cases that code is just fine. I am not an expert but that is probably because the map wants coordinates and stuff which the emulators don't have. So the solution is simple, just run it to your android device and it ought to work if your code is OK.

Answer (score 1):

After fighting against this, I discover that if install the GApps in the emulator fixes the problem. Now the app is running without problem